# Pytorch: a similar process to reverse pooling and replicate padding?

Tags: python, pytorch, inverse, max-pooling

I have a tensor `A` that has shape `(batch_size, width, height)`. Assume that it has these values:

```py
A = torch.tensor([[[0, 1],
                   [1, 0]]])
```

I am also given a number `K` that is a positive integer. Let `K=2` in this case. I want to do a process that is similar to reverse pooling and replicate padding. This is the expected output:

```py
B = torch.tensor([[[0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0]]])
```

Explanation: for each element in `A`, we expand it to the matrix of shape `(K, K)`, and put it in the result tensor. We continue to do this with other elements, and let the stride between them equals to the kernel size (that is, `K`).

How can I do this in PyTorch? Currently, `A` is a binary mask, but it could be better if I can expand it to non-binary case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Square expansion

You can get your desired output by expanding twice:

```py
def dilate(t, k):
  x = t.squeeze()
  x = x.unsqueeze(-1).expand([*x.shape,k])
  x = x.unsqueeze(-1).expand([*x.shape,k])
  x = torch.cat([*x], dim=1)
  x = torch.cat([*x], dim=1)
  x = x.unsqueeze(0)
  return x

B = dilate(A, k)
```

#### Resizing / interpolating nearest

If you don't mind corners potentially 'bleeding' in larger expansions (since it uses Euclidean as opposed to Manhattan distance when determining 'nearest' points to interpolate), a simpler method is to just [`resize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67127742/9067615):

```py
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F

B = F.resize(A, A.shape[-1]*k)
```

---

For completeness:

> [`MaxUnpool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxUnpool2d.html) takes in as input the output of `MaxPool2d` including the indices of the maximal values and computes a partial inverse in which all non-maximal values are set to zero.

Comment: how about replicating in the channel dimension and then apply `PixelShuffle`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

**Note**: The below functions takes a 2D tensor as input. If your tensor `A` is of shape *(1, N, N)* i.e., has a (redundant) batch/channel dimension, pass `A.squeeze()` to `func()`.

**Method 1**:

This method broadcasted multiplication followed by transpose and reshape operations to achieve the final result.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

A = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]])
K = 3

def func(A, K):
    ones = torch.ones(K, K)
    tmp = ones.unsqueeze(0) * A.view(-1, 1, 1)
    tmp = tmp.reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1], K, K)
    res = tmp.transpose(1, 2).reshape(K * A.shape[0], K * A.shape[1])
    return res
```

**Method 2**:

From @Shai's hint in comments, this method repeats the (2D) tensor in channel dimension `K**2` times and then uses [PixelShuffle()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.PixelShuffle.html) to upscale the row and column by `K` times.

```py
def pixelshuffle(A, K):
    pixel_shuffle = nn.PixelShuffle(K)
    return pixel_shuffle(A.unsqueeze(0).repeat(K**2, 1, 1).unsqueeze(0)).squeeze(0).squeeze(0)
```

Since `nn.PixelShuffle()` takes only 4D tensors as input, unsqueezing after the `repeat()` was necessary. Also note, since the returned tensor from `nn.PixelShuffle()` is also 4D, the two `squeeze()`s followed to ensure we get a 2D tensor as output.

**Some example outputs**:

```
A = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
func(A, 2)
# tensor([[0., 0., 1., 1.],
#         [0., 0., 1., 1.],
#         [1., 1., 0., 0.],
#         [1., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

---

```
pixelshuffle(A, 2)
# tensor([[0, 0, 1, 1],
#         [0, 0, 1, 1],
#         [1, 1, 0, 0],
#         [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Feel free to ask for further clarifications and let me know if it works for you.

**Benchmarking**:

I benchmarked my answers `func()` and `pixel shuffle()` against @iacob's `dilate()` function above and found that mine are slightly faster.

```
A = torch.randint(3, 100, (20, 20))
assert (dilate(A, 5) == func(A, 5)).all()
assert (dilate(A, 5) == pixelshuffle(A, 5)).all()

%timeit dilate(A, 5)
# 142 µs ± 2.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit func(A, 5)
# 57.9 µs ± 1.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit pixelshuffle(A, 5)
# 81.6 µs ± 970 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the 2D tensor, I will use `repeat_interleave`.

```
>>> import torch
>>> x = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> x
tensor([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
>>> torch.repeat_interleave(x, 2, dim=0)
tensor([[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4]])
>>> torch.repeat_interleave(x, 2, dim=1)
tensor([[1, 1, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 4, 4]])
>>> torch.repeat_interleave(torch.repeat_interleave(x, 2, dim=0), 2, dim=1)
tensor([[1, 1, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 4, 4],
        [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```